# How to wrap angular material form into a component & expose them to FormGroup as a formControl element

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-forms, angular-reactive-forms

I am trying to encapsulate a component (for example called `custom-input`) as a formControl element based on Angular material components to contain the following:

```
<mat-form-field >
  <input
    matInput
    [formControl]="inputField"
    formControlName="{{ name }}"
    name="{{ name }}"
    maxlength="{{ maxlength }}"
    placeholder="{{ name | translate }}"
    required
  />
  <mat-error *ngIf="inputField.errors">{{
    this.validationService.getErrorMsg(inputField.errors)
  }}</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

Now this component is working with the needed functionality ***but can't be bound to formGroup using the formControlName attribute like the normal input or matInput*** (like the below for example, which is bound directly to the formGroup without issues)

```
<input
  matInput
  formControlName="inputField123"
  placeholder="{{ 'testInput' | translate }}"
  required
/>
```

The question is how to enable the composed component above to be bound as a formControl element in the formGroup? what should I implement or expose to provide this functionality?

Should I use ControlValueAccessor or there is a better way that shall be used for Material input components?

Comment: "Should I use ControlValueAccessor". Yes.

Answer (score 8):

After searching around for long time, mainly because the `ControlValueAccessor` was advised for the primitive html parts (like input or so, not for material components, which I thought might have some easier wrapping technique)

I finally found out that we can implement `ControlValueAccessor` as advised, or since this is an input field, we can use `DefaultValueAccessor` like this

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-test-input',
  templateUrl: './test-input.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test-input.component.css'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => testInputComponent),
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class testInputComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
  @Input() name = '';
  @Input() maxlength = 250;
  @Input() width = 30;

  @ViewChild(DefaultValueAccessor) valueAccessor: DefaultValueAccessor;

  writeValue(obj: any) {
    this.valueAccessor.writeValue(obj);
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: any) {
    this.valueAccessor.registerOnChange(fn);
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: any) {
    this.valueAccessor.registerOnTouched(fn);
  }

  setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean) {
    this.valueAccessor.setDisabledState(isDisabled);
  }

  constructor(public dataService: DataService) {
  }

}
```

The html part is like this:

```
<mat-form-field fxFlex="100" >
  <input
    matInput
    formControlName="{{ name }}"
    maxlength="{{ maxlength }}"
    placeholder="{{ name | translate }}"
    required
  />
  <mat-error *ngIf="matInputSelector.errors">{{
    this.dataService.getErrorMsg(matInputSelector.errors)
  }}</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

### Note

if I use `formControlName="{{ name }}"` I can bind the control to the `formGroup`, however, I can't use the `formControl` attribute to bind to the error part of the component

i.e: I can either use:

1- formControl (can control the error part)

OR

2- use formControlName (binded to the outer formGroup, but can't control the error part)

So if someone has a better answer, please post it to help everyone.

Comment: Hi Ahmed!
Where did you define "matInputSelector"? I cant see it in your code.

Comment: How did this work for you? The `valueAccessor` is only available in the "AfterViewInit" lifecycle and the `writeValue` method is called earlier so it ends up with errors.